# Best design pattern for queueing and sending batches of TCP messages

Tags: design-patterns, tcp, queue, messaging

I have a relatively simple requirement to write a windows service which performs the following tasks and wanted some advice on the simplest and best design pattern to use.

1. Return X number of rows from a SQL server stored proc
2. Convert each row into a message and send to a TCP server
3. Once all messages are sent, go back to step 1

A mechanism will need to exist which detects if the TCP connection has entered a half opn/closed state such as sending a message and receiving a response from the server after each batch of messages has been sent.  If no response comes back we will need to reconnect and resend the currect batch.  Messages MUST be delivered to the server.  We will store the ID of the last polled message in the database so that we can restart from where we left off if the service was to sto/crash/restart for any reason.

Speed is massively important as we need to get the data into the TCP server as close to real-time as possible.

The application will be written in .net 4.0.

Thanks, I look forward to hearing your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the messages and frequency of polling and security constraints I might take different approaches however my quick short response would be like the following:
On Client side : I will read the messages into a 'transnational' queue in a polling thread then on another thread
I will send these messages to the server by calling the WCF service which I have setup on my server which processes the rows I am passing to using my client proxy.

On the Server side I will setup a WCF service [use TCP binding if it is outside the networking infrastructure of the company] which will process my data.

Comment: Thanks Socrates, I was looking for specific examples of tried and tested design patterns that might exist to solve this particular problem.